# ROS Kinetic GUI Help

Tags: ros, qt, ros-kinetic, gui

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,
I need help creating a GUI for ROS Kinetic. I tried the ROS - QML - Plugin and no luck. Any guidance , tutorials , or advice on how to go about this will be appreciated. Essentially , I want the GUI to be a node and collect and receive information. Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275578/ros-kinetic-gui-help/) by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-11-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there! I've done this before, you need to use QT, and communicate via qt_ros.
If you don't know what QT is, well it's an IDE for C++ that can be configured to work with ROS (https://ros-industrial.github.io/ros_qtc_plugin/) Once you set QT you can debug your programs, build, and create workspaces with QT.

But if you install QT just like in the link provided above, you'll also have QT Designer that allows you to design C++ interfaces very easily (Drag and Drop and configure) so you'll have something like this:

[image: image description]

Once you design your interface and have it as an .UI extension, you can load that and publish/subscribe to different topics within ROS. Check the tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/qt_create/Tutorials/Qt%20App%20Templates

But you'll have a nice interface with ROS topics communication, which is what I think you want to achieve:

[image: image description]

Good luck and happy coding!

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2017-11-13**:
Your the man!

**Comment by [Valveware](https://answers.ros.org/users/32824/valveware/) on 2018-01-11**:
How can I find the Ros Master URI and the host IP when running Roscore on my ubuntu? And when I am testing it on the turtlebot? When I start roscore it says 'started roslaunch server http://basestation:38583/' That should be the Master_URI and my laptop's ip address should be the ROS IP, right?

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2018-01-11**:
Yes indeed @Valveware , you find the Master IP by just doing an `ifconfig` and checkig the IP of the adapter you are using, of course you have to do that in the machine that is being the master, so lets say that if my laptop is the master, the MASTER_IP will be the one of the laptop.

**Comment by [Valveware](https://answers.ros.org/users/32824/valveware/) on 2018-01-11**:
Thanks a lot, I got it to work, the MASTER_URI roscore reported to me was wrong. I could find the correct one by echoing $ROS_MASTER_URI.

**Comment by [MechLc](https://answers.ros.org/users/29880/mechlc/) on 2018-01-11**:
@bpinaya he knows the way